# Does completing quests at different levels actually give you different XP?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

In Star Wars: The Old Republic, doing quests up to six levels below yours yields a chunk of experience points (XP). Across the SW:TOR forums, people say to maximize experience, do orange level quests (quests at a higher level than you). But, because of experience devaluation, does this actually affect how much experience I gain from those quests?

Example: Mission A yields 5000 XP upon completion at level 25. But, at level 26, it yields only 4000 XP. This would seem to indicate that it would grant me a greater bonus at level 25. But, from level 25 to 26, everything suffers a 20% experience drop. I can't defeat the same mobs for the same amount of experience; they've dropped from 100 XP to 80 XP. The game has obscured the fact that it has both increased the experience you require to make it to the next level (100K for level 25, 120K for level 26), but also decreased the experience you receive from everything, essentially doubling the actual effort increase for levelling (100K to 120K, but decreasing your gains by 20% means levelling would require 150K XP at the level 25 XP "value"). So, completing Mission A, you still gain 5000 XP at the level 25 value; but, converting it to the level 26 value, you see a 4000 XP gain.

Does it work this way I have described, or do you in fact gain more equivalent XP for higher level quests (e.g. 5000 XP at level 25, 3500 XP at level 26 with only a 20% devaluation of XP, meaning you only gain 4375 level-25-equivalent XP)?

Basically, if I will reach a level in 1 XP, and have two quests to complete, one at 8000 XP, and one at 5000 XP, will it matter which quest I choose to complete first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below is now outdated.  Patch 4.0 added Level Sync, which ensures that you are scaled up or down to the level of the planet you're on.  It also further ensures that XP rewards are properly matched to your actual level, so that you can do any kind of content available to you in any order to level up.

---

Higher level quests give more XP than lower level quests, but this is not scaled linearly by the XP increase from level to level; it's significantly lower.  In other words, if Level 10 requires 50,000 XP and Level 20 requires 5 times more at 250,000 XP, the average Level 20 quest completed at Level 20 will give you less than 5 times the XP of the average Level 10 quest completed at Level 10.  (And/or the level 20 question will simply take longer; your "normalized XP" per minute goes down.)

So you have to do more and more content to increase one level as your level goes up; it takes much longer to get from level 19 to 20 than it does to get from level 9 to 10, for example.  And doing content below your level is certainly an inefficient way to continue levelling.

To answer the new question you've added: Complete the 8000 XP quest first, because that way only 5000 XP will be "diluted" by your next level and not 8000.  You shouldn't be worrying about this though, it's not going to matter.  Levelling easily is not a matter of lining up quests to maximize every potential; just play.

Comment: As a F2P player, I find myself 3+ levels below some of my class quests at times, so I'm trying to find small ways to help catch up.

Comment: @palswim Only thing I can tell you is to make sure you do some of the optional content.  When levelling my first 50 prior to the current sub XP boost (same as F2P is now) I did all the class quests, all the planet quests (apart from a few heroics), and some Space missions and I was ahead of the curve.  There's also PvP and Flashpoints, and there are experience boosts on the GTN for fairly cheap.